# Change shortcode output (filter?)

Tags: filters, shortcode

I'm new to filters and actions and I'm starting to see how useful they are. However I do need a bit of help with the following problem.

I'd like to remove the html code from this

```
<?php if ( $atts['columns'] != 0 && $i % $atts['columns'] == 0 ) { ?><div style="clear:both;"></div><?php } ?>
```

to the one below inside my functions.php

```
<?php if ( $atts['columns'] != 0 && $i % $atts['columns'] == 0 ) { ?> <?php } ?>
```

Can anyone put me in the right direction?

Full source code:

```
    // Allow the query to be manipulated by other plugins
    $query = apply_filters( 'edd_downloads_query', $query, $atts );

    $downloads = new WP_Query( $query );
    if ( $downloads->have_posts() ) :
        $i = 1;
        $wrapper_class = 'edd_download_columns_' . $atts['columns'];
        ob_start(); ?>
        <div class="edd_downloads_list <?php echo apply_filters( 'edd_downloads_list_wrapper_class', $wrapper_class, $atts ); ?>">
            <?php while ( $downloads->have_posts() ) : $downloads->the_post(); ?>
                <?php $schema = edd_add_schema_microdata() ? 'itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" ' : ''; ?>
                <div <?php echo $schema; ?>class="<?php echo apply_filters( 'edd_download_class', 'edd_download', get_the_ID(), $atts, $i ); ?>" id="edd_download_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" style="width: <?php echo $column_width; ?>; float: left;">
                    <div class="edd_download_inner">
                        <?php

                        do_action( 'edd_download_before' );

                        if ( 'false' != $atts['thumbnails'] ) :
                            edd_get_template_part( 'shortcode', 'content-image' );
                            do_action( 'edd_download_after_thumbnail' );
                        endif;

                        edd_get_template_part( 'shortcode', 'content-title' );
                        do_action( 'edd_download_after_title' );

                        if ( $atts['excerpt'] == 'yes' && $atts['full_content'] != 'yes' ) {
                            edd_get_template_part( 'shortcode', 'content-excerpt' );
                            do_action( 'edd_download_after_content' );
                        } else if ( $atts['full_content'] == 'yes' ) {
                            edd_get_template_part( 'shortcode', 'content-full' );
                            do_action( 'edd_download_after_content' );
                        }

                        if ( $atts['price'] == 'yes' ) {
                            edd_get_template_part( 'shortcode', 'content-price' );
                            do_action( 'edd_download_after_price' );
                        }

                        if ( $atts['buy_button'] == 'yes' )
                            edd_get_template_part( 'shortcode', 'content-cart-button' );

                        do_action( 'edd_download_after' );

                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php if ( $atts['columns'] != 0 && $i % $atts['columns'] == 0 ) { ?><div style="clear:both;"></div><?php } ?>
            <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

            <div style="clear:both;"></div>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php
                $pagination = false;

                if ( is_single() ) {
                    $pagination = paginate_links( apply_filters( 'edd_download_pagination_args', array(
                        'base'    => get_permalink() . '%#%',
                        'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, $query['paged'] ),
                        'total'   => $downloads->max_num_pages
                    ), $atts, $downloads, $query ) );
                } else {
                    $big = 999999;
                    $search_for   = array( $big, '#038;' );
                    $replace_with = array( '%#%', '&' );
                    $pagination = paginate_links( apply_filters( 'edd_download_pagination_args', array(
                        'base'    => str_replace( $search_for, $replace_with, get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                        'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, $query['paged'] ),
                        'total'   => $downloads->max_num_pages
                    ), $atts, $downloads, $query ) );
                }
            ?>

            <?php if ( ! empty( $pagination ) ) : ?>
            <div id="edd_download_pagination" class="navigation">
                <?php echo $pagination; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
        <?php
        $display = ob_get_clean();
    else:
        $display = sprintf( _x( 'No %s found', 'download post type name', 'edd' ), edd_get_label_plural() );
    endif;

    return apply_filters( 'downloads_shortcode', $display, $atts, $atts['buy_button'], $atts['columns'], $column_width, $downloads, $atts['excerpt'], $atts['full_content'], $atts['price'], $atts['thumbnails'], $query );
}
add_shortcode( 'downloads', 'edd_downloads_query' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using *str_replace*.

```
function mp_filter_download( $result ) {
        $search         = '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
        $replacewith    = ' ';      
        return str_replace( $search, $replacewith, $result );
}
add_filter( 'downloads_shortcode', 'mp_filter_download', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: If you accept your answer then the question will be marked as resolved.  Thanks.